# Notifications lost after app is idle for longer duration - one signal sdk in flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I have implemented one signal sdk to receive notifications. I receive notifications when the app is in background. As the app is removed from the background I receive notifications for sometime but after that I do not notifications. As the app is idle for long time (overnight) app is unable to receive notifications from one signal dashboard. As soon as I open the app and put in background/ remove it from background I start receiving the notifications. Can anyone help me here? I tried putting the app Data saving mode but that did not help. I have the app process running in the background tasks when I am not able to receive the notifications.

Comment: are you using FCM for  notification

Comment: I am using one signal dashboard to send notifications